# Should I create service to record audio in background?

Tags: android, android-service, mediarecorder

I've create an application which record audio via `MediaRecorder` class. In the activity, the MediaRecorder object is released (and record stopped) only when user request it (button) or when the activity is destroyed (`onDestroy()`), not paused (`onPause()`). So, I'm able to record audio when app is in background.

But, is it very safe? I would avoid the application to be destroyed while recording. Is a service help me in that case? Which is cleaner?

I guess that I should create a service that handle MediaRecorder and start it with `startForeground()`, but I'm not sure.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need/want to record audio outside your app ?

Comment: @StephaneMathis My need is to record audio even if app is in background. So user can do anything he wants while recording.